# Inverse of "being a fan of"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

"Y has 1250 fans" means there are 1250 `X` for which `X` is fan of `Y`. If there are 12 `Y` for which the "X is a fan of Y" relationship holds for a given `X`, what's a word or phrase to say "X has 12 *_*_" ?

Similarly, if "X is a fan of Y", then what's the equivalent way of saying this with Y as the subject and X as the object ("Y *_*_ X") ?

Comment: AFAIK, the (boring) answer is that there's no inverse (unless you specify the type of Y, at least). For your second blank, you can fill in "has as a fan" (or, more conventionally, "Y has X as a fan").

Answer (score 5):

> "Y has 1250 fans" means there are 1250
>   X for which X is fan of Y. If there
>   are 12 Y for which the "X is a fan of
>   Y" relationship holds for a given X,
>   what's a word or phrase to say "X has
>   12 __" ?

As [Jeffrey Kemp](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/inverse-of-being-a-fan-of/3050#3050) and ShreevatsaR pointed out in an answer and a comment, there is not really one distinct answer to this question. But there are lots of possible words you could use depending on the context. For example

> X has twelve **idols**

or

> X has twelve **heroes**

or

> X has twelve **favourite stars**

Comment: X has twelve favo(u)rites

Answer (score 1):

I don't think English has any word which is the inverse of "fan" - apart from the phrase "is a fan of".

"X is a fan of 12 people"

"Y has a fan in X"

Comment: I was afraid so.. it's actually worse because in my case the "Y"s are not just people or any other single group; they may be people, sport teams, music bands, etc, so it would be something like "X is a fan of 12 entities/things/???", none of which sound particularly good..

Comment: Really?  You would say "Y has a fan in X"?  I find this rather awkward.

Comment: If I google for "* has a fan in *" there are quite a few examples.

Comment: @gsakkis: If the Ys are not all the same type, really what sense or purpose does it have to count them? If I were a fan of 3 athletes, 4 movies and 6 restaurants, I can imagine no context in which it would be useful to say "I am a fan of 13 _____" or "I have 13 _____". (In any case I'd have trouble enumerating all the people/things I'm a fan of without being prompted for type, and I assume the same is true for most people.) (Even among "people", I don't see the purpose in adding, say, the number of athletes and number of actors I may be a fan of, but "people" works there.)

Comment: Just use the term "favorites". Favorite movie, favorite religion, favorite sports team, favorite flavor of ice cream, favorite brand of computer.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that fan derives from "fanatic," which usually implies exclusivity, so it's hard to truly be a "fan" of 12 unrelated people or things.